# Hide form when main form run is hide also in start up

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I have a small project about manage time use on computer.
Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Timer t = new Timer();
    public static int counter = 60;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
        t.Interval = 1000;
        t.Enabled = true;                       
        t.Start();
        Form2 TheForm2 = new Form2();
        TheForm2.ShowDialog();
    }

    void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter -= 1;
        if (counter==20)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Time remaining "+counter.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

And Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int userVal = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        Form1.counter += userVal;
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = Form1.counter.ToString();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Final program:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Form1 TheForm = new Form1();
        Application.Run();
    }
}
```

I try to make this application run on Windows start up and the Form1 is hide. But I wanna make form2 invisible also. And it just show when user excute the application. How can I solve it?
I just put this exe to folder start up to make it run on start.(I'll try to make it with Registry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to control the visibility of one form from another form. To do so, use the `.Visible` attribute of the form. For example:

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
        t.Interval = 1000;
        t.Enabled = true;                       
        t.Start();
        Form2 TheForm2 = new Form2();
        TheForm2.ShowDialog();
        TheForm2.Visible = false;
    }
```

There are other issues with the way you are doing this, but I presume you will sort those out over time, or post other questions :)

**Edit:**
OK, I have modified your code to demonstrate how to make this work. The code compiles and runs for me, and shows how to make form2 initially invisible, then make it visible after 10 seconds have elapsed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TwoForms
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            // If you do it this way you'll have to stop the application yourself
            // Form1 TheForm = new Form1();  
            // Application.Run();

            Application.Run(new Form1());   // When Form1 is closed, the application will exit.
        }
    }
}
```

Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TwoForms
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
            private Timer t = new Timer();
            public static int counter = 60;
            public Form TheForm2;
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                t.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
                t.Interval = 1000;
                t.Enabled = true;
                t.Start();
                this.Show(); // show Form1 just so we know it's really there
                TheForm2 = new Form2();
                // TheForm2.ShowDialog(); // Don't do this unless you really want a modal dialog
                TheForm2.Show();
                TheForm2.Visible = false; // A timer tick will later set visible true
            }
        void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter -= 1;
            if (counter == 50)
                TheForm2.Visible = true;
            if (counter == 40)
                MessageBox.Show("Time remaining " + counter.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TwoForms
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int userVal = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            Form1.counter += userVal;
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = Form1.counter.ToString();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's because of the other issues I mentioned. For one thing, don't create TheForm2 inside the constructor of form1 -- instead, make Form2 a field or property belonging to Form1. You can instantiate it within the constructor, but don't declare it there.

Comment: Thank you so much for help.